# Why do we need to use dynamic properties?(matlab2020a code)

Tags: matlab, oop, properties, dynamic-properties

**Why do we need to use dynamic properties? In what situations must we use dynamic properties? What value do they bring? If I must add a property, why not add it within the class instead of adding a dynamic property to the object?**

The book I'm reading provides examples of dynamic properties, but I find that they seem to function like regular variables. Furthermore, it seems like this program can achieve its goals without dynamic properties. Please take a look at the code below.

```
classdef  MyButton < dynamicprops
    properties
        UiHandle
    end
    methods
        function obj = MyButton(pos)
            if nargin > 0
                if length(pos) == 4
                    obj.UiHandle = uicontrol('Position',pos,...
                        'Style','pushbutton');
                else
                    error('Improper position')
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The book instructs to execute the following commands.

```
hbutton1 = MyButton ([20 40 100 40]);   
addprop(hbutton1,'Caption');  
hbutton1.Caption='OK';
set(hbutton1.UiHandle,'String',hbutton1.Caption)
```

However, I found that removing dynamic properties does not affect the outcome.

```
hbutton1 = MyButton ([20 40 100 40]);
hbutton1.UiHandle.String='OK'
```

Comment: Cross posted here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2017171-why-do-we-need-to-use-dynamic-properties?s_tid=srchtitle

Comment: “Why do we need to use …” you don’t need to, you **can** use if it’s convenient, you shouldn’t if it’s not.

Comment: @CrisLuengo The purpose of my asking this question is: not only to learn how to use the tool but also to understand when to use which tool. I believe that MATLAB must have provided dynamic properties for a specific reason, and it's definitely not intended for users to use it as a variable for storing temporary data. If I am unaware of the special value of dynamic properties, I won't be able to fully utilize their true potential!