# What software functionality requires triggering callback functions by adding or removing dynamic attributes?（matlab2020 code）

Tags: matlab, properties, software-design, application-design, matlab-app-designer

"In MATLAB, it appears that only '[dynamic properties](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/matlab_oop/dynamic-properties-adding-properties-to-an-instance.html?s_tid=srchtitle_site_search_1_dynamic%20properties&requestedDomain=en)' can trigger built-in events（[PropertyAdded/PropertyRemoved](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/matlab_oop/dynamic-property-events.html?s_tid=srchtitle_site_search_2_PropertyRemoved)） when added or removed. For example, in the following code snippet. But from a product design perspective, the necessity of using the addition/removal of 'dynamic properties' to trigger callback functions for changing text in a figure is not very significant.

So, in which software requirements is it necessary to use the addition/removal of dynamic properties to trigger callback functions?"

---

```
%main.m
function main()
clear all
clc
import MyFigure.*  %Import packge

%Creat a figure object fig_obj
fig_obj=MyFigure([0.2,0.2,0.50,0.50]);

%Creat class AddDynoProFigHandlea;=AddDynoProp(fig_obj);
%pause;  %暂停

%Add 'dynamic properties'Data for fig_obj through object ab
ab.AddPropForMyFigure(fig_obj,'Data');

%Use findprop to obtain the meta.DynamicProperty object corresponding to the member 'Data'
m = fig_obj.findprop('Data');

%将函数set_Data的句柄指派到SetMethod成员上
m.SetMethod = @set_Data;

%成员Data的数据设置    
fig_obj.Data=peaks;

delete(ab);
end
```

MyFigure.m

```
%+MyFigure\@MyFigure\MyFigure.m
classdef  MyFigure<dynamicprops
    properties
        FigHandle;    %图形窗口句柄
        AxHandle;    %轴对象句柄
    end
    methods
        function obj = MyFigure (pos)  %构造函数
            if nargin > 0
                if length(pos) == 4
                    obj.FigHandle = figure('Unit','normalized','Position',pos,...
                        'Name','动态属性成员事件演示','NumberTitle','off',...
                        'MenuBar','none');
                else
                    error('Improper position')
                end
            end
            obj.AxHandle =axes('Parent',obj.FigHandle,...
                'Unit','normalized',...
                'Pos',[0.1,0.1,0.7,0.8]);
            uicontrol('Parent',obj.FigHandle,...
                'Unit','normalized',...
                'Pos',[0.82,0.1,0.15,0.1],...
                'Style','pushbutton',...
                'String','退出',...
                'Callback','close');
        end
    end
end
```

AddDynoProp.m

```
%+MyFigure\@AddDynoProp\AddDynoProp.m
classdef AddDynoProp < handle
    properties
        mp;  %动态属性成员对应的meta.DynamicProperty对象
    end
    methods
        %构造函数，evtobj为产生事件的对象
        function obj = AddDynoProp(evtobj)
            if nargin > 0
                %创建两个听众
                addlistener(evtobj,'PropertyAdded',@MyFigure.AddDynoProp.PropEvents);
                addlistener(evtobj,'PropertyRemoved',@MyFigure.AddDynoProp.PropEvents);
            end
        end
        %在对象evtobj上添加属性成员DynoPropName为产生事件的对象
        function AddPropForMyFigure(obj,evtobj,DynoPropName)
            obj.mp = evtobj.addprop(DynoPropName);
        end
        %析构函数
        function delete(obj)
            delete(obj.mp);  %删除动态属性成员
        end
    end
    methods (Static)
        %回调函数
        function PropEvents(src,evnt)
            switch evnt.EventName
                case 'PropertyAdded'
                    title(src.AxHandle,'PropertyAdded 事件发生了');
                case 'PropertyRemoved'
                    title(src.AxHandle,'PropertyRemoved 事件发生了');
                    set(src.AxHandle,'Visible','off');
            end
        end
    end
end
```

set_Data

```
function set_Data(obj,val)
obj.Data = val;
surf(obj.Data);  %绘制Data的曲面图
end
```

Comment: This is related to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77048004/7328782), and very much in the same vein. If you don’t need it, ignore it. If you ever come across a situation where this would be useful, then you know it exists and you can use it. Most language features do not have one specific use case. They are things that some people thought might be useful, and so added them to the language.

Comment: In particular with callbacks, you can attach one to most events in MATLAB, including setting and reading object properties. It is only logical that adding or removing a property to an object is also an event you can attach a callback to. Maybe someone, somewhere, has a use for this. Don’t worry if you can’t think of one, this feature was not designed for you. You don’t even have a use case yet for adding a dynamic property, why would you care that it triggers an event that you can attach a callback to?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I want to gain more experience through learning and accumulating knowledge. Combining the code from books with practical work can potentially yield more insights and benefits.